# ≤ shown as £; ≥ shown as ³

Tags: programming-languages

I have a printed answer to a math problem which has weird symbols on it. I figured out that the symbols were just incorrect renderings of usual symbols. Do you know what might have caused this?

Comment: That is probably a problem with whatever software you use to print it out. If it is LaTeX, learn how to write mathematics in it.  You have to enclose math in `\(...\)` (for inline equations) or (et least) `\[...\]` (for displayed ones). Or you are using Unicode characters (like the ones in your title), while the printing expects ASCII (or another encoding).  Without a lot of further details, nobody will be able to help: What software are you using? Give a *minimal*, complete file that shows the problem.

Comment: Questions about consumer software are off-topic here, though in principle one could answer this question by explaining different encoding schemes and how they could clash.